# IISにWCFサービスを配置しないで、WCFクライアント側のテストを可能にするWCFサービスを用意したい

Tags: c#, wcf

タイトルの件、WCFサービスを利用するクライアント側の単体テストをしたい場合に、
ローカル環境で閉じている仮想的なWCFサービスを用意、動作させることは可能でしょうか？

環境はVisual Studio 2013 でC#での開発となります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCFサービスは`ServiceHost`を利用して[自己ホスト](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms750530(v=vs.110).aspx)が可能です。自動テストであれば実際のWCFサービス、もしくは同じサービスコントラクトを実装するモックをホストすればよいと思います。

またIIS ExpressやIISを用いてローカルマシン上でWCFサービスを実際にIISでホストするのも難しいことでありません。手動テストであればVisual Studioで「マルチスタートアッププロジェクト」でクライアントとWCFサービスを同時にデバッグすることもできます。